# How do I isolate handwritten text from an image using OpenCV and Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, handwriting-recognition

How do I isolate or crop only the handwritten text using OpenCV and Phyton for the image:

[image: Handwritten image]

I have tried to use:

```
cv2.findContours
```

but because of the noise (background and dirty in paper) I can't get only the paper.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To smooth noisy images, typical methods are to apply some type of blurring filter. For instance `cv2.GaussianBlur()`, `cv2.medianBlur()`, or `cv2.bilaterialFilter()` can be used to remove salt/pepper noise. After blurring, we can threshold to obtain a binary image then perform morphological operations. From here, we can find contours and filter using aspect ratio or contour area. To crop the ROI, we can use Numpy slicing

---

Detected text

[image]

Extracted ROI

[image]

Code

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,8)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=6)
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite('ROI.png', ROI)
    break

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('ROI', ROI)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: I did not work for me. I copied your code but the ROI prints the top of the image, the part above of paper.

Comment: Using the input image you provided, I'm getting the correct result. Is your input image a .png or .jpg? Try with the updated code. The result should be the same

Comment: I image is jpeg. Here is the ROI: [ROI](https://imgur.com/O4nsxAl) and the three together: [three](https://imgur.com/flWXsmq). Thanks for help.

Comment: Your dilate image is different from mine. Very weird. Are you sure you have `cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5)` and `iterations=6`? Try change `iterations=6` to `iterations=15`

Answer (score 1):

0. Convert image to single channel gray.
1. Apply [adaptiveThreshold](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga72b913f352e4a1b1b397736707afcde3) to your image. Handwriting will become of black color, rest will be white.
2. If you want to get segmentation for this word as a solid thing, then also apply [morphologyEx](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f), with `MORPH_CLOSE`. Here you should play with kernel, most likely it will be ellipse 3x3, and number of iterations, usually 5-10 iterations is ok.

```py
   kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(shape=cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, ksize=(3, 3))
   image = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=7)
```

3. Use [connectedComponentsWithStats](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga107a78bf7cd25dec05fb4dfc5c9e765f). It will put every char into separate component. `stats` will hold bounding boxes either for whole word, or (if you omit step #2) it will hold info for each connected characters group.

P.S.: Let me know if you need full code example.